# Jenkins dynamic stage with agent none

Tags: jenkins, agent, executor

I have a declarative pipeline, that in one stage make a script where perfom some validations with an if/else block, and in one of this condition I declare a stage with an input (I only want that this stage can be executed in this particular condition) the problem is that I want that input not lock the executor will wait for the user input, but it execute in the agent declared up in the stage, is possible to overwrite the agent to declare as none?

Here a resume of the pipeline:

```
pipeline{
    agent none
    stages{
        ...
        stage('branch-selector'){
            agent{
                label 'runner'
            }
            steps {
                script {
                    if (BRANCH_NAME.contains('feature')){
                        print "in branch feature"
                    }
                    if (BRANCH_NAME == 'develop'){
                        print "in branch develop"
                    }else if (BRANCH_NAME == 'release_candidate'){
                        print "in branch rc"


                        stage('Confirm deploy'){
                            milestone ordinal: 10, label: "Promote Aproval Milestone"
                            input message: "Are you sure you want to promote"   
                        }

                        stage('Deploy'){
                            print "Deploy"                  
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use: when
https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when

So you execute step only when your condition is meet. And no extra magic necessary.